# Mapbox Markers - Dynamic markers on one layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Is it possible in mapbox to have only one layer on which I'll add many markers dynamically (e.g. when the user will zoom on the map) or remove them dynamically (e.g. when the user zooms out)?

Another question related to the first one: is a marker a layer? If so, what's the difference between the class L.Marker and a layout?

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [`L.mapbox.featureLayer`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-mapbox-featurelayer/), which is a single layer defined as a group of markers.  You can then add and remove markers programmatically like this:

```
var markerGroup = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geojson).addTo(map);
markerGroup.addLayer(marker);
markerGroup.removeLayer(marker);
```

As to whether a Marker is a Layer, the answer is sort of...A Marker is a UI Layer, as distinguished from a Raster Layer and a Vector Layer.

Comment: Interesting...For what I see on the doc, you can add geoJSON to a featureLayer at once, but can you do it dynamically? I have a fonction addMarker(lat, lon) that will be called once the map is loaded by the user...

Comment: Yes you can.  `featureLayer` inherits from [`LayerGroup`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-layergroup/) and layerGroup has `addLayer` and `removeLayer` methods.

Comment: @bom4new - i added some code to my answer so you can get an idea of how you might add/remove markers from your featureLayer